# Resizing PDF pages to uniform size

Tags: command-line, pdf, resizing

I have a multi-page PDF file. Due to the nature of its making (scanning with a camera and then cropping), the pages are all in different (but similar) sizes. I would like to perform resizing on each of the pages, so that they become exactly the same size. By "resizing", I mean rescaling the width and height **separately to fill the target page size** (that is, not necessarily preserving the original aspect ratio).

The closest thing I can find is `cpdf -scale-to-fit 150mm 200mm input.pdf -o output.pdf`, but this command preserves the aspect ratio, resulting in undesired white padding space. Not exactly what I want.

Any idea how to achieve the effect?

Comment: As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726628), ImageMagick can do it. Further reading: [`page` option](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#page) and [Image Geometry](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry)